# What is a method I can use to remind users they've entered a location?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Geofence API for iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473995/geofence-api-for-ios-5)

My goal: Send an alert to my application's user when they enter a predefined location.

I've considered:

1. Setting up methods to be called in the background by iOS upon major location changes. The problem is this process must be (or at least *appears* that it must be) manually initiated every time the iPhone restarts.
2. Using the Event Kit framework to create location-based reminders. The problem I've encountered is that there are no methods listed in the documentation that allow me to do this programmatically.

Can anyone offer suggestions on other ways to go about alerting my users of their entry to a predefined location? Did I miss something when reading the documentation for CLLocation and EKFramework? Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy: method on CLLocationManager.