# iOS: communicating GPS position change to remote web service when app is running in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background, gps

I would like to implement a geofence based domotic activation system.

There are different ways to define a geofence ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473995/geofence-api-for-ios-5)). What I am concerned about is how this will all come together (service activation).

I am thinking of the use case where the geofence is set up by the user via phone (say via the App I am developing). Once this is done then the data will be stored in a remote webservice. iOS app development guidelines says that you **cannot have an app running in the background** and here my doubts start..

The point of defining the geofence is to activate some domestic/domotic service once the user enters the geofence that he defined as house. However **if the App is running on background how can I get the app to communicate the position to the web service?**

I have found [this tutorial](http://redth.codes/ios7-recipe-background-fetching/) on remote background data fetching.

Apple developer [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) mentions that you can get background location change updates and hence I assume I can have some code to perform certain actions within the app when I receive a location change call back (from the location manager service). If this is correct I am then wondering whether combining this step plus using [remote posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700572/ios-7-background-upload-and-post-requests) of data may be a valid solution (this has to happen when the app is in background mode).

If not would you be able to suggest an alternative approach?

Comment: Enable "Location update" and "Background fetch" in Background Modes. Then you can make request even in background. We made a app like you said and release on App Store.

Comment: @PowHu thanks for the comment. Would you be ok to share the link of your app here? It will be useful to understand how you approached the UX

Comment: Cool thanks. Can't read Japanese but it is an interesting market. Japan is very interesting for these technologies. Was the client side code complex to develop?

Comment: It's not complex. Use CLLocationManager and get user location in "locationManager:didUpdateLocations:" then save to server.Server side we use Parse.com

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you request notifications within a geo fence you app will be woken up to get the notification, you can use this notification to then request a background session, which can then be used to update your web service.